# should I keep using self.__local_object all over the code?

Tags: python, oop, code-readability

I'm extending a former colleague's code (Python3) and find personally those repeated `self.__local_object.x=some_result` annoying and hindering readabilit. I.e. instead of

```
 self.__local_node.sign("computing partition for joining node %f<?<%f"%(
        self.__local_node.partition_id,next_neighbour.partition_id))
    partition_id = 0
    if(next_neighbour != self.__local_node):
        partition_id = PartitionID.gen_btw(self.__local_node.partition_id, next_neighbour.partition_id)
```

I'd rather use

```
 ln=self.__local_node
 ln.sign("computing partition for joining node %f<?<%f"%(
     ln.partition_id,next_neighbour.partition_id))
 partition_id = 0
 if(next_neighbour != ln):
     partition_id = PartitionID.gen_btw(ln.partition_id, next_neighbour.partition_id)
```

However, I'm not yet seasoned with Python development and I may be missing a golden guideline that will make further maintenance a nightmare if I introduce such (hopefully) local aliases for referenced objects.

PS: no, `self.__local_node`'s value is not altered any place in that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really don't change the value, only assingn or access its attributes, this should be perfectly ok.

Answer (score 2):

Since `local_node` and `next_neighbour` are symmetrical, it might be a good idea to extract the code into a separate method:

```
def compute_partition(self, a, b):
    a.sign("computing partition for joining node %f<?<%f" % (
        a.partition_id, b.partition_id))
    partition_id = 0
    if a != b:
        partition_id = PartitionID.gen_btw(a.partition_id, b.partition_id)
    etc...

....

self.compute_partition(self.local_node, next_neighbour)
```

a bit more readable in my view. Also, there must be very good reasons (or excuses) for using double underscores. Check if it's possible to get rid of them in your case.

Comment: I thought double underscore were the way to have "private" members in python. I have to admit I hadn't tried single underscores so far.

Comment: @sylvainulg: double underscores invoke name-mangling rules (see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables), and can be used to "obscure" the name. Mostly not a good idea.

Comment: "To avoid name clashes with subclasses, use two leading underscores to invoke Python's name mangling rules." -- that sounds like the very definition of a private member to me: noone from outside should be allowed to alter it. I admit it's a real pain when debugging and coding, btw.

Comment: the refactoring you suggest here is interesting and mind-opening, btw.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be surprised if all the members of the **__local_node** object used the belong to the class referenced here as **self**, and this is the product of a copy and paste rampage.

Comment: you mean like self.partition_id would be there and there would be no need to do self.__local_node.partition_id ? This is actually not the case.

Comment: Hmm well that's not how I would write it. Perhaps have another read of **The Zen of Python** and see how it feels. I totally agree and would write it your way.

Comment: Thanks for the book suggestion. I'm struggling to find a book that goes to the point and explain python, not loops and conditional expressions... libraries around here are just pitiful in that regards.

Comment: Haha no book needed, only python. Try `import this` in your interpreter whenever you get lost.